# Существует ли метод работы с Google Street View на Python?

Tags: python

Пишу проект, возник вопрос с генерацией случайных координат (широта, долгота), на которых есть панорама `Google Street View`. Сделать это надо на Python. Есть ли какие-нибудь способы сделать это, или надо использовать другие IP?